# Execute an Action from another controller (n) times (Play Framework)

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm trying to execute an Action from ControllerB (n) times, and return the result.

```
class ControllerB extends ... {
  def single = Action.async {
    ...
  }
}

class ControllerA extends ... {
  def multiple(rep: Long) = Action.async {
    List.range(0,rep).foreach( Await(routes.ControllerB.single) ... ?  )
    Future(Ok("finished " + rep + " runs of function"))
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how exactly the Await part should be written. Also if there's a way to make this Action async as well.

Comment: Action are not meant for that. I would suggest you refactor the action as a "plain" function that can be called from any controller, any times.

Comment: Makes sense, in case of a "traditional" design, the "single" function should live entirely in the service layer, then be called multiple times from the ControllerA. Thanks.

Comment: @cchantep, your comment is correct, so write an answer (preferably with some simple sample) so OP can accept and upvote it.